# How to filter line in bash?

Tags: bash

Whenever I run `flutter run`, there's a bug on my phone that prints

```
I/ViewRootImpl@afe5448[MainActivity](22885): [DP] cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate$2@3308abc  isViewVisible: true
```

like 100 times.

Is there a way to filter those in bash? Whenever `ViewRootImpl` appears, just don't print that line

Comment: `flutter run | grep -v ViewRootImpl` ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some context. Why is a phone relevant? Is this Android? On the command line? @ilkkachu you likely want `flutter run 2>&1 | grep -v ViewRootImpl`.